# Consulta SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Buenas estoy tratando de ejecutar esta consulta pero me tira el siguiente error

> 'Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   PRSPROM_EMISOR_COMISION_DETALLES, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 13]
>   Invalid column name 'PRODUCT'.'

la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
        CONCAT(E.BIN,E.COD_EMISOR) AS PRODUCT,
        E.NOMBRE AS EMISOR,    
        S.NOMBRE AS SUBPRODUCTO,
        P.NOMBRE AS PRODUCTO,          
        C.NOMBRE AS COMISION,
        C.VALOR                     
FROM TMPRO_EMISOR E
        INNER JOIN TRPRO_EMISOR_SUBPRODUCTO ESUB ON E.ID = ESUB.ID_EMISOR    
        INNER JOIN TMPRO_SUBPRODUCTO S ON ESUB.ID_SUBPRODUCTO = S.ID 
        INNER JOIN TMPRO_PRODUCTO P ON S.ID_PRODUCTO = P.ID
        INNER JOIN TRPRO_EMISOR_COMISION EC ON E.ID = EC.ID_EMISOR 
        INNER JOIN TMPRO_COMISION C ON EC.ID_COMISION = C.ID 
WHERE (@pCOMPANIA IS NULL OR E.ID_COMPANIA = @pCOMPANIA)
       AND(@pBIN_COD_EMISOR IS NULL OR PRODUCT LIKE '%' + @pBIN_COD_EMISOR +'%')
       AND (@pCOMISION IS NULL OR EC.ID_COMISION = @pCOMISION)
```

Agradezco la ayuda que se me pueda brindar,

Saludos.

Answer (score 5):

`PRODUCT` es un alias de columna que es una de las últimas cosas de la consulta   que resuelve el motor. El `WHERE` se resuelve antes, por lo que no existe el alias en dicha instancia, que es lo que haces aquí:

```
AND(@pBIN_COD_EMISOR IS NULL OR PRODUCT LIKE '%' + @pBIN_COD_EMISOR +'%')
```

Debería modificar el código anterior por algo así:

```
AND(@pBIN_COD_EMISOR IS NULL OR CONCAT(E.BIN,E.COD_EMISOR) LIKE '%' + @pBIN_COD_EMISOR +'%')
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio Moracho